# Thread.sleep vs Task.delay in rest api

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, azure, async-await

I was comparing Thread.sleep vs task.delay. to check for a job completion status from db. The job will be performed by some other Azure component .

To test it, Created small api with sync and async pattern.

http rest api using async :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    return await Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage());}
```

http rest api using sync :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    Thread.sleep(200);
    return new HttpResponseMessage();}
```

Interestingly. the results were good for Sync call. Tried with 100 users with 5 iteration using Apache jmeter.

> Sync result.: min : 414 ms average : 8464 ms
>
> Async result : min 1756 ms average : 10044 ms

Why Thread.sleep is better than Async. is this overhead of Task creation? Can't I get better results than these two?

Comment: The `async` isn't purposed for lower latency - there is lot of infrastructure around so higher latency in compare to more "bare bone" calls is expectable. And btw it's unclear what is meant by "better results".

Comment: You can simplify the code as follows: `return new HttpResponseMessage();` - no need `await Task.FromResult`

Answer (score 2):

The point of asynchronous code is not to improve performance of an individual operation. In fact, as you can see, sometimes it's the opposite.

The point of asynchronous code is to not lock the current thread. The benefits depend on the type of application:

**Desktop app** (I know this doesn't apply to you, but it's worth mentioning)

In a desktop app, you don't freeze the UI thread. This way, your UI remains responsive to the user while you wait for the response from some I/O operation.

So while the individual operation might take *slightly* longer, the user isn't frustrated because the UI isn't frozen.

**Web app**

In a web app, it frees up the current thread to work on the next request that has come in. ASP.NET has a limited number of threads to use, so if your traffic is busy enough, requests might have to wait before being processed. Asynchronous code helps you avoid that.

For example, a synchronous I/O operation will lock the current thread (like `Thread.Sleep`). The thread can do nothing else until the operation completes.

If you use asynchronous code (like `Task.Delay`), then once that asynchronous operation starts, the thread is returned to the thread pool and can be used to process another request while it waits.

So while individual operations might take *slightly* longer, it allows you application to handle a bigger load.

Microsoft's documentation on this is actually quite excellent: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: The point of asynchronous code is to execute something asynchronously, that is not in strictly predicted order. It can release thread or can be single-threaded. The point of asynchronous I/O is to offload an I/O operations to certain infrastructure which to free up the CPU resources but that's just an example of asynchronous code applicability. And `Thread.Sleep` has nothing to do with I/O.

Comment: *" And `Thread.Sleep` has nothing to do with I/O."* - Yes, I know. But in this question, `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` are being used as placeholders for synchronous and asynchronous I/O operations. For that purpose, they work.

Comment: No, they don't, as they have totally different nature than I/O operations underneath, so test them as a substitution of I/O is unfair as well as treat them that way.

Comment: It's not a perfect substitution, no. But in my experience, they are very useful is observing the difference between how async and non-async functions behave. This question is a perfect example of that.

Comment: That's not true as if we are talking about I/O operations specifically (not just wide range of asynchronous operations) then the main goal of using asynchronous I/O is scalability. And the difference in this quality attribute (in case of sync vs async) isn't measurable and isn't observable in case of using any substitution of async I/O. So while they can be useful to measure any other difference but salability they can be substituted but as you stated that they're placeholders for I/O this measurement at least unfair, at worst useless.

Comment: So please, rephrase your answer in order to avoid incorrect statements.